# Can I inject external script files with executeScript() in MV3?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Is the code below fine in MV3? I was wondering if it could be published on Chrome Web Store.

```
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tabId },
    func: () => {
      const tag = document.createElement('script')
      tag.src = 'https://my-server/script.js'
      document.head.appendChild(tag)
    },
    args: [],
    world: 'MAIN'
  })
```

The code was able to be uploaded as unpackaged extension MV3 and executed.

I referred to the information.

> extension developers can use the scripting.executeScript() method to either inject a static file or a function. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#executing-arbitrary-strings

Comment: No, this code won't be allowed on CWS (once a human reviewer sees it, so maybe not immediately) and no, executeScript only accepts internal file names or function, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. So there's no way to inject external files in MV3?

Comment: See https://crbug.com/1239976